# What pattern is used to stop a component from double (multiple) rendering in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that calls an expensive API to fill its values.  In development it would double call the API.  This question is slightly redundant since I think this is known feature and doesn’t happen once built.  But it brings up the question of how do you stop double/multiple renders from happening if you encounter it?

```
useEffect{() => {
    if (!isLoading) {
        setIsLoading(true);
        // call API and fill fields
    }
}
```

doesn’t work because `setIsLoading` is run asynchronously so might not fire until after a 2nd call to render the component. I imagine this is a common scenario. Is there is a code pattern to deal with this in React?

Comment: Can you describe your problem better or add additional code? If you talk about double rendering with for example console.log, you can remove React strictmode from App.js

Comment: @skar I think the use of strictmode is the solution to having the double rendering problem when developing.  My question is how to handle this issue in a generic sense, how (what pattern) can you use to stop a component from double/multiple rendering.

Comment: Why not try doing the api call in a parent component, it could be that the useEffect is triggering again because the child component is re-rendering, or the parent could be-rendering something which is causing the child to re-render, also it's good practice to put the empty dep array `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by implementing two `useEffect` functions instead of one.  Set a state variable `isInitialRender` or something like that to true, have your first `useEffect` switch it to false, then have a second `useEffect` that executes when `isInitialRender` changes and only runs if it's false.

Here's what it would look like:

```js
const [isInitialRender, setIsInitialRender] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsInitialRender(false);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!isInitialRender) {
    // Call API
  }
}, [isInitialRender]);
```

Additionally, as Nikster mentioned in their comment, passing that empty array as the second argument in the first `useEffect` means that first `useEffect` will only be called upon the component's initial mount (well, twice in development mode), so you should include it if you want to avoid re-setting isInitialRender to false and re-triggering the second `useEffect` every time the component re-renders.